# How can I obtain Absolute Altitude Value (ASL) using DJI MSDK and M300 drone

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to get the drone absolute altitude value (ASL) in real time (before taking off)

I have 2 drones, Mavic 2 enterprise advanced & M300.

When using the below code in mavic2, I was able to obtain the ASL, however the same code returns NULL value when using with M300:

```
Object heightAboveSeaLevel = KeyManager.getInstance().getValue(FlightControllerKey.create(FlightControllerKey.ABSOLUTE_GPS_ALTITUDE));
```

Also tried with no luck the below:

```
DJIKey GPSKey = FlightControllerKey.create(FlightControllerKey.ABSOLUTE_GPS_ALTITUDE);
DJISDKManager.getInstance().getKeyManager().getValue(GPSKey, new GetCallback() {
    @Override public void onSuccess(@NonNull Object value) {
        
    }
    @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull DJIError error) {
        
    }
});
```

On a side note, when using the M300, the ASL value is shown in the DJI Pilot app.
[image: M300 Fpv view in dji pilot app]

Anyone has accomplish the above or has any ideas to what I should use?

Answer (score 0):

This is from DJI:

This KEY does not currently support the M300. Do you know how to use MSDK V5, which provides the KEY for obtaining real-time altitude: KeyRTKAbsoluteAltitude?
MSDK V5：https://developer.dji.com/doc/mobile-sdk-tutorial/cn/